# WooCommerce - change custom base slug to product-category slug

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I have tried figuring this out for two days with WooCommerce custom slug based.

I have links like mydomain.com/product/product-category/t-shirts/ and I want it to be mydomain.com/product-category/t-shirts/

Yes, want to remove product or store name from the link to get good SEO.

I need to change my product permalinks with a custom base, but when I am trying to set "**/%product_cat%/**" then automatically it converts to "**/product/%product_cat%/**" or **/%product_cat%/product/**.

Finally, I want to set permalinks like this - mydomain.com/fashion(Main Category)/t-shirts(Sub Category)/my-t-shirt-1(Product Name)

Would really appreciate some help!

Thanks

Comment: i found this at [the end of the docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/permalinks/): "Please note: The product custom base should not conflict with the taxonomy permalink bases". Could it be your case?

Comment: Found this neat little article on it, try this out!

http://ryansechrest.com/2013/04/remove-post-type-slug-in-custom-post-type-url-and-move-subpages-to-website-root-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to achieve is not possible with Woocommerce.

If you do want to remove the slug from products or categories you can use a plugin. There are several plugins available, I don't know if I am allowed to post it here, Here what I've used -

1- Install free 'WOO CATEGORY BASE PERMALINK FIXER' plugin from https://masterns-studio.com/code-factory/wordpress-plugin/woo-category-base/

2- Set Product Category Base Permalinks to: shop

3- Set Custom Base Permalinks to: /shop/%product_cat%/

URLs will then look like

`http://www.example.com/shop/category/sub-category/product`

Seems to work fine for pagination and subcategories.

Comment: That's not useful to me. I want slug like below,

(http://www.example.com/parent-category/sub-category/product-slug)

I hope that will help you for the correct answer.